# Android Search Interface Tutorial

Tags: android, search

I did the first part of this tutorial...

http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

I made the options_menu.xml and added the code to the onCreateOptionsMenu() method. After I run my app on my device it turns on and automatically crashes. Sorry I don't know if I formatted the LogCat message below properly but I copy / pasted into here so it may help determine what the problem is, I'm not sure how to read it or fix the issue. Let me know if I can format it more properly or maybe export other error messages if needed. Under "Problems" I have two...

1. the import android.os Build is never used
2. The import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar is never used

not sure if thats important...Thanks!

```
03-30 19:13:06.266: W/ApplicationPackageManager(17378): getCSCPackageItemText()
03-30 19:13:06.326: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(17378): Parent view is not a TextView
03-30 19:13:06.436: I/Adreno-EGL(17378): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
03-30 19:13:06.436: I/Adreno-EGL(17378): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.07
03-30 19:13:06.436: I/Adreno-EGL(17378): Build Date: 01/22/14 Wed
03-30 19:13:06.436: I/Adreno-EGL(17378): Local Branch: base_au149_adreno_au169_patches
03-30 19:13:06.436: I/Adreno-EGL(17378): Remote Branch: 
03-30 19:13:06.436: I/Adreno-EGL(17378): Local Patches: 
03-30 19:13:06.436: I/Adreno-EGL(17378): Reconstruct Branch: 
03-30 19:13:06.466: D/OpenGLRenderer(17378): Enabling debug mode 0
03-30 19:13:06.496: W/ResourceType(17378): getEntry failing because entryIndex 1 is beyond type entryCount 1
03-30 19:13:06.496: W/ResourceType(17378): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0c0001 (t=11 e=1) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
03-30 19:13:06.496: D/AndroidRuntime(17378): Shutting down VM
03-30 19:13:06.496: W/dalvikvm(17378): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417adda0)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378): Process: com.example.csbizsearch, PID: 17378
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c0001
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2009)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3224)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1825)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:115)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at com.example.csbizsearch.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:30)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2588)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:486)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:855)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:271)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
03-30 19:13:06.506: E/AndroidRuntime(17378):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 19:13:09.836: I/Process(17378): Sending signal. PID: 17378 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I added this line import android.view.MenuInflater; and I get one new error "Error executing aapt: code 138

Comment: Well I got well beyond this point with Android Studio but still have lots of errors in Eclipse like this so I guess I will just move to Android Studio from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've havent got this error in Android Studio so I will continue to use this instead of eclipse...If anyone finds the a solution to this that would be great though!!