# App Crash When perform Add record in green dao using async task

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app todo list for demo.

Using async task to handle persist record (Using greenDAO) in background.

After add record, it will go back to listing screen.

When development is fine but now it is crash all the time.

The most i can found is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752670/android-search-interface-tutorial)

Thanks for watching. :)

[Logcat as below]

```
D/AbsListView(2116): unregisterIRListener() is called 
 W/ResourceType(2116): No known package when getting value for resource number 0xff149e60

 D/AndroidRuntime(2116): Shutting down VM
 W/dalvikvm(2116): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4180dc08)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116): Process: com.jobm.mobile, PID: 2116

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xff149e60

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2009)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1584)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16144)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at com.jobm.mobile.adapter.FriendAdapter.getView(FriendAdapter.java:86)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2720)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1801)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1641)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2533)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15655)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15655)

 E/AndroidRuntime(2116):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
```

Comment: Please post the source code that throws this exception.

Answer (score 0):

the origin of the problem is certainly one of this :the dependency injection to your item lsit ressource or you put int value in a textview.

Comment: Actually i don't use any DI library in project, the value input in textview able to get by using .getText().toString() before process.
you may have a look at the simplify code above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for watching and willing to help.

First, my problem was solved.

Second, Errors is happened when it loading the listview and item in it, and the resource does't match with what i have set for the color in item.

Sorry for wasting your time :)